# PyOpenCL Install Trouble on Mac OS X El Cap 10.11.3 with Enthought Canopy 1.6.2.3262

Tags: python, macos, enthought, pyopencl

Versions:
pyopencl 2015.2.4
Mac OS X 10.11.3
Xcode: 7.2.1
Enthought Canopy 1.6.2.3262

I am trying to install PyOpenCL on Mac OS X 10.11.3 with Enthought Canopy and I am having difficulty.  Following directions on the PyOpenCL wiki:

python configure.py
make

I get the following output:

```
rovitotv-mbpr15:pyopencl-2015.2.4 rovitotv$ python configure.py
rovitotv-mbpr15:pyopencl-2015.2.4 rovitotv$ make
ctags -R src || true
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ctags: illegal option -- R
usage: ctags [-BFadtuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...
/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python setup.py build
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry, your build failed. Try rerunning configure.py with different options.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 234, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 230, in main
    zip_safe=False)
  File "/Users/rovitotv/prog/pyopencl-2015.2.4/aksetup_helper.py", line 21, in setup
    setup(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.6.2.3262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 271, in __init__
    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.6.2.3262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 326, in finalize_options
    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
  File "/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 161, in cffi_modules
    add_cffi_module(dist, cffi_module)
  File "/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 48, in add_cffi_module
    execfile(build_file_name, mod_vars)
  File "/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 24, in execfile
    exec(code, glob, glob)
  File "cffi_build.py", line 32, in <module>
    ffi = FFI()
  File "/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 56, in __init__
    import _cffi_backend as backend
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/rovitotv/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so
  Reason: image not found
make: *** [all] Error 1
rovitotv-mbpr15:pyopencl-2015.2.4 rovitotv$
```

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with the Canopy package manager I was able to get pyOpenCL built and running on my Mac.  The solution I came up with was I went into the Canopy Package Manager and updated cffi.  After the cffi update I just reran the build and install steps as documented on the [pyOpenCL wiki](https://wiki.tiker.net/PyOpenCL/Installation/Mac).  After the install I ran a number of PyOpenCL examples.  Thanks!